# d3.selectAll only elements with classes in element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

how can i use d3.selectAll with classes in element.

Here is an example which describes my problem:

Please no jquery and no pure javascript. I need d3.selectAll because i have d3 databinding

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4rtwetfc/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
</div>

<div id= "two">
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
let one = document.getElementById("one")
let two = document.getElementById("two")
let allElements = d3.selectAll(".test")
console.log(allElements)
// Now i want only from div one
let div1Elements = d3.selectAll("???")
// Now i want only from div two
let div2Elements = d3.selectAll("???")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
let div1Elements = d3.selectAll("#one .test");
// Now i want only from div two
let div2Elements = d3.selectAll("#two .test");
```

or like this

```js
let one = d3.select("#one")
// Now i want only from div one
let div1Elements = one.selectAll(".test");
console.log(div1Elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
<p class="test">a</p>
<p class="test">b</p>
</div>

<div id= "two">
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
</div>
```